# JWT authoritzation the right way

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest, jwt

I am developing a platform that has 3 applications, probably going to be 4.

First one is the client website, made using phalconPHP, second one is the clients intranet, where he can manage his website, the there is the administrator, where I can create new websites and manage my customers.

Last one is the API, everything should be accesible via API too.

My initial plan is to use JWT as authoritzation method, I have some doubts thought.

1.- Once JWT token has been created, I need to store it somewhere on the client so that I can be sent on every new request, what I don't know is where to store so that PHP can access it and Javascript can access it too so that I can make AJAX requests with the token.

I need a way to make this possible in a secure way, HTTPS will be always used in my app, but there is this one problem that I'm not sure how to solve.

I repeat, JWT token should be accesible by both, JS and PHP. How do I do this in a secure way?

Also, I was thinking about adding the PHP_session_id into the JWT payload, and add auto-renew too, that means that a token is usefull only for "user" that made the log-in. Is this aproach secure?

Hope you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: since you intend to use JWT, your server shouldn't use PHPSSID, because your server should be stateless.

Comment: Not that way, I was thinking that when the user logs in, phpssid should be send along with username and password, and then if login is succefull, phpssid will be included in the JWT payload, this way I can make sure that if someone steals the JWT token it will be useless.

Comment: this is exactly the state. if you use a loadbalancer or similar and the request goes to another server your token would then be invalid. the expiration of the token should be very short and there should also be another reissue token, where you can update the actual valid token.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Now the important part, where do I store the JWT so both Javascript and client application done in PHP can access it in a safe way?

Comment: take a look at this [link](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/) they describe it very well. if you have to send only php requests, I think the way to go are cookies, since with php you can't read html5 storage.

Comment: I found that post before, but in a normal app even thought most of the data will be read of php requests there are gonna be some AJAX requests.

I can't believe i'm the only person that needs to send JWT tokens both with PHP requests and with AJAX requests, somebody must have found a way to make the token available to both.

Comment: actually, you can if the HttpOnly flag is not set. I think the discussion in the blog post, is about xsrf and xss which I think could also occur if you don't use the flag is not set. But this is only my opinion.

Comment: So the conclusion is there is no way to securely store a JWT token on a client so that it is accesible by both Javascript and PHP?

That means I have to handle csrf and xss defending mechanisms by myself?

Thanks in advance Raphael